# React Native says function doesn't exist when trying context for routing and auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my first real mobile app and when I am trying to implement auth and routing I am running into some issues - both error message and I am guessing functional too

My app currently has two stacks, an auth stack, and a drawer stack. I have the auth stack as the default stack and want to display the drawer stack if the user is logged in. If they are logged out show them the auth stack till they login.

I have this line of code in my root stack navigator

```
{ auth ? <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStack} />:<Stack.Screen name="Drawer" component={DrawerStack} />}
```

Above my stack navigator I have this line

```
const { auth } = checkAuth()
```

Which is imported using - correct file path

```
import { AuthProvider, checkAuth } from '../context/AuthContext'
```

The base code from that import is below

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

    const checkAuth = () => {
      try {
        const authData = globalStorage.getString('accessToken')
        if(authData !== null && authData !== undefined) {
          setAuth(authData)
        }
      } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    }

  const removeAuth = () => {...};

  const setAuthState = data => {
    try {
      console.log('setAuthState Data: ', data)
      globalStorage.set('accessToken', data)
      setAuth(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuthState, removeAuth}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The error message I am seeing in the iOS simulator is that `checkAuth` is not a function. I am not sure why it isn't when I am doing the import. I tried adding the `AuthProvider` as a prepend but no luck. I am sure this is a simple React thing but I'm not sure as I don't normally code this way when I do Node.js work.

Edit

```
import { AuthProvider, checkAuth } from '../context/AuthContext'

...


const AppNavigation = () => {
  return (
      <AuthProvider> <-- Error on this line
        <RootNavigator />
      </AuthProvider>
  );
};

...
```

Error message

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.React.createElement')
```

Comment: You haven't shown what you are `export`ing from the `AuthContext` file, but since you've defined `checkAuth` within the `AuthProvider` function, there isn't a way for you to be exporting the `checkAuth` function from it anyway. You can use `const {auth} = useContext(AuthContext);` to grab the value of `auth` instead of trying to use `checkAuth()`

Comment: @NickParsons Sorry for delay SO didn't let me know of reply till email today. Anyways, I am getting an error about something being undefined when I am using the code in my edit of the OP. This only occurs when I use the code you provided so not sure if broken in some other way?

Comment: Hi, are you exporting AuthProvider from your file?

Comment: @NickParsons I am using `export { AuthProvider };` at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

`checkAuth` is scoped to `AuthProvider`. You'll want to include it in the `value` prop of `AuthContext.Provider` if you want make it available to consumers of your `AuthContext`, but I'd imagine you'll just want to use `auth` which is already provided to consumers.

Here is some info on the `useContext` hook where you can access those properties. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext